Opening a new window / tab with zsh adds a new line into .zshrc file
everytime i open a new terminal prompt in MacOSX, it adds a new line into my .zshrc:
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
how can I find the source of what's adding this and stop it?
I tried looking at the zsh advanced settings to see if there's anything adding into the zshrc on startup and nothing. Also looked at homebrew documentation but didn't see anything.

When you open a terminal tab, your terminal application (you did not write which one you use) runs that program it is configured to run; in most cases, this will be a shell, such as bash, fish or (likely in your case: zsh). A shell processes certain startup files, depending on how it is invoked. If your .zshrc is modified every time, one of the commands in the startup files is doing this. Hence you just have to find this command and fix it.
